# creating a record in a table automatically after saving the other record in tne other table rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, belongs-to

I still novice with RoR. My mission is to add examplaries according to the number of exemplary inserted in the form of book, knowing that i have a book table and an examplary table and the relationship in between is a book has_many exemplaries and an exemplary belong_to a book.
This is my attempt:

in books_controller.rb
method create:

```
 def create
    @book= Book.new(book_params)

     if @book.save
      @book.nbr_exemplaires.times do |i|
        @exemplaire= Exemplaire.create(book_id:  @book.id, state: 0 )
      end

      flash[:notice]='goood'
      redirect_to admin_manage_path
     else
       flash[:alert]='ouups'
       redirect_to root_url
     end
  end



  private

   def book_params
     params.require(:book).permit(:title, :pages, :resume,:nbr_exemplaires, :has_exemplaires,       :author_ids =>[], :subject_ids =>[])
    end
```

book/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
          <%= form_for(@book) do |form| %>
          <div> <%= form.label :title %><br>
            <%= form.text_field :title %>
     </div>
     <div>
       <%= form.label :pages %><br>
       <%= form.number_field :pages %>
      </div>
      <div>
         <%= form.label :resume %><br>
         <%= form.text_area :resume %>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>select author from existing list</p><br>
         <%= form.collection_select :author_ids, @authors, :id, :l_name, {:selected => 1}, {:name => 'book[author_ids][]'} %>

     </div>
      <div>
         <p> Select subject from existing list</p><br>
           <%= form.collection_select :subject_ids, @subjects, :id, :name, {:selected =>1}, {:name => 'book[subject_ids][]'} %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= form.label :has_exemplaires? %>
         <%= form.check_box :has_exemplaires,{}, 'Yes', 'No'%>
           <div id="expl_details" style="display:none;">
            <%= form.label :nbr_exemplaires %> <%= form.number_field :nbr_exemplaires %>

          </div>
         </div>
         <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
       <% end %>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         var checkbox = document.getElementById('book_has_exemplaires');
         var details_div = document.getElementById('expl_details');
         checkbox.onchange = function() {
           if(this.checked) {
              details_div.style['display'] = 'block';
           } else {
             details_div.style['display'] = 'none';
           }
          };
         </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I would suggest something like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exemplaires

  attr_accessor :nbr_exemplaires
  after_save :create_exemplaires

  private 

  def create_exemplaires
    nbr_exemplaires.times do
        self.exemplaires.create()
    end
  end
```

If you actually have a column name 'nbr_exemplaires' in your table, you don't need the attr_accessor line. That is only if you won't be saving that as separate value in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would use nested attributes, that way rails will create them automatically for you through the same form:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exemplaires
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exemplaires, allow_destroy: true
```

This would allow to use the nested form builder in your view:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |form| %>

  <div><%= form.label :title %><br>
       <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :exemplaires do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
     ... more fields
  <% end %>
```

You could then add some javascript to create a multiple nested forms:

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Exemplarie", f, :answers %>
```

With this kind of setup, rails will automatically create all the associated objects in the same action with no additional code on the controller/model side. Here is a great railscasts on it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

If you haven't subscribed, I suggest you do. It's the most useful rails resource I ever used when starting out and it costs only a few $ a month. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for responding but what i really want to do is whan the user  enter how many exemplary has the book and at this momment automatically some records are added to the exemplary table according to the number entred by the user